# Adding custom styles to dropdown in editor

Tags: customization, wp-admin, editor, visual-editor, code

is it possible to add a custom style to the dropdown in the classic WordPress editor, say a `div` with the class of "`fancywords`"?

[image: that dropdown in editor]

Comment: Since that's really meant for text formatting rather than adding divs, you might look into creating a shortcode instead.

Comment: how about a `p` with a class of `fancywords`?

Comment: You'd have to mess with TinyMCE to add anything to the dropdown. A shortcode would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to your functions.php

```
function add_style_select_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
// Register our callback to the appropriate filter
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'add_style_select_buttons' );
//add custom styles to the WordPress editor
function my_custom_styles( $init_array ) {  

    $style_formats = array(  
        // These are the custom styles
        array(  
            'title' => 'Fancy Words',  
            'block' => 'div',  
            'classes' => 'fancywords',
            'wrapper' => true,
        )
    );  
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

    return $init_array;  

} 
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init' 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_custom_styles' );
```

After adding the code when you select your text in the editor and choose the formatting from the `Formats` dropdown you will see a div wrapper with your class named **fancywords**.

[image]

For displaying the style in the editor you need to do couple of more steps.

1. Create a file name **wp-editor-style.css** or any name you like you wish in root folder of your active theme. You can add the style in this file, i.e. `.fancywords { background: #4ab9ff; color: #fff; font-family: 'Oswald'; }` 
   **NOTE**: If you change the file name here, change the same in the next step too.
2. Add this code in your active theme functions.php

   `function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
       add_editor_style( 'wp-editor-style.css' );
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );`

Comment: I don't see it when I add that code to my functions.php

Comment: Not sure. It can be due to your active theme or any plugin. I have tried the code myself and attached a screenshot of the result for the same. You can try to activate twenty twenty or any basic theme and try that code in functions.php

Comment: Oh I see it, I wasn't toggling the toolbar

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how do you make the style visible in the editor?

Comment: Do you have the style that you want?

Comment: Yes, `.fancywords {
    background: #4ab9ff;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
}
`

Comment: @Gusto I have just edited my answer with the solution to your last query. Do let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works, thanks